# GitVersion Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/GitVersion.Tool/5.12.0/x64/dotnet-gitversion'

Tags: flutter, github, github-actions, cicd, gitversion

Im implementing CI/CD process with github actions into my flutter app, Im using gitversion to manage verions that is my actions file configuration

```
name: desarrollo_ci_cd
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:

  version:
    name: Creando numero de compilacion
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3

        - name: Install GitVersion
          uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v0.10.2
          with:
            versionSpec: '5.x'

        - name: Use GitVersion
          id: gitversion
          uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.10.2
       
        - name: Create version.txt with nuGetVersion
          run: echo ${{ steps.gitversion.outputs.nuGetVersion  }} > version.txt

        - name: Upload version.txt
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
          with:
            name: gitversion
            path: version.txt
```

On github panel the pressese was stopped on Use GitVersion step with this error:

```
Error: Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/GitVersion.Tool/5.12.0/x64/dotnet-gitversion' failed with exit code 1
```

Trying with diferent version in versionSpec but with the same result

i wanna create a version.txt file to get version when build appbundle

Comment: Make sure you have the correct version of GitVersion specified. Check the GitVersion documentation or the GitHub repository for compatibility information. Try specifying a specific version instead of using a version range to ensure consistency.

Check if you have the necessary permissions to run GitVersion in your GitHub Actions workflow. Ensure that the workflow file has the required permissions to execute GitVersion commands.

Comment: Verify that the GitVersion tool is installed correctly on the runner machine. You can add a step to print the version of GitVersion to check if it is properly installed. For example:

Comment: `- name: Verify GitVersion installation
  run: dotnet-gitversion --version
`

Comment: Double-check if your repository structure and branch naming align with GitVersion's conventions. GitVersion relies on branch names and structure to determine versioning. Make sure your branches follow the required naming conventions.

Review the GitVersion logs to get more information about the specific error that occurred. You can try adding the verbose flag to the dotnet-gitversion command to enable verbose logging. For example:

Comment: `- name: Use GitVersion
  id: gitversion
  uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.10.2
  with:
    args: '--verbose'
`